# Cannot import name izip

Tags: python, csv

I´m trying to transpose a matrix from a csv-file with the following code:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
a = izip(*csv.reader(open("TDM.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb")).writerows(a)
```

Unfortunately the following error occurs:

```py
from itertools import izip
ImportError: cannot import name 'izip'
```

I already looked through the forums but couldn´t find the right answer for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess you use Python 3.

Use `zip()` builtin instead.

In Python 3 there is no `itertools.izip()` as the `zip()` builtin behaves similarly.

Comment: Using zip() still gives me an error:
from itertools import zip

ImportError: cannot import name 'zip'

Code: 
import csv
from itertools import zip
a = zip(*csv.reader(open("TDM.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb")).writerows(a)

Comment: @Nils_Denter do not import it. It is [a builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) - it is always available (unless overwritten by an assignment).

Comment: Ok now it works, but i get a new error:
    a = zip(*csv.reader(open("TDM.csv", "rb")))
Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: @Nils_Denter Did you? I can see "b" as "binary". ;)

Comment: Ah thank you, I´m really new to python. My mistake.

Comment: No need to import in python 3 just use zip() and it will work.