# Importing error of Panda_gbq in VM(Virtual Machine in Google cloud platform)

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, virtual-machine, lzip

I am trying to save BigQuery results as a dataframe. I tried to use `to_dataframe() - Uses BigQuery tabledata.list API` but its very slow. 
So, I am trying to use `pandas_gbq` but when I try to import in Jupyterlab in virtual machine then I get this error. [image]

I installed even using pip but getting same error. Any help?

Comment: Actually, it looks like this post will help you more accurately than my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239706/cannot-import-name-izip

Comment: Can you tell me how do you run Jupyterlab on VM, have you followed any tutorial for this e.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-jupyter-on-a-google-cloud-vm-5ba1b473f4c2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this package is not installed on your instance of Jupyerlab. You should install it (you only need to do this once) and run your code again.

Since you are in Jupyterlab, you can import from inside your notebook my prefixing your shell command with `!`.

For example:
`!pip install pandas`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already tried this and i am getting same errror. `Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (0.25.3)` and then `ImportError: cannot import name 'lzip'`

Comment: CheCK out my comment on your question, i feel this link is more helpful to you?

Comment: Yes i did. But still the same problem.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Check this the answers to this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833698/pandas-cannot-import-name-compat